# stored procedure out return always 0.0

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am a newbie to jdbc my program always return 0.0... help

```
 CallableStatement cs= con.prepareCall("{ call  getbalance(?,?) }");
    cs.setInt(1, 1234);
    //cs.setString(2, "dfdf");
    cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.DOUBLE,23);
    cs.execute();
    System.out.println("Balance is "+ cs.getDouble(2));

             CREATE PROCEDURE `getbalance`( acno int, out amt int)
              begin 
                       select bal * amt from bank WHERE accno=acno; 
               end;
```

Answer (score 1):

For setting the parameters, what is the account number? Is it 1 or 1234?

```
cs.setInt(1, 1234);
```

You may not have a record with the acno you are inputting...

You have typed,

```
select bal * amt from bank WHERE accno=acno;
```

Shouldn't it be the following, given you have both input and output parameters

```
select bal INTO amt from bank WHERE accno=acno;
```

the edited SP would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getbalance`( IN acno int, OUT amt int)
 AS
    BEGIN 
                 SELECT bal INTO amt FROM bank WHERE accno=acno; 
    END;
```

Comment: 1 is index for parameters and 1234 is value passed

Comment: `cs.setInt(1, 1234)` is absolutely correct. There is no parameter with the index 1234 in that statement.

Comment: Blimey! Got that part boggled. However the setting into out parameter and rest is correct in the answer if that's what OP intended to do. Multiplying Bal by amt will return zero. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this, set value to amt variable.

```
Set amt = (select bal * amt from bank WHERE accno=acno);
```